# Database concurrent usage issues - updates to table after items already closed by another user

Tags: sql-server, concurrency

This is more of a concurrent use of software by multiple users. Consider the tables below

```
Table: ShippingList
ID  Status
--  ------
1   PENDING SUBMIT
2   COMPLETE
3   DRAFT

Table: ShippingListItems
ID  ShippingListId Value
--  -------------- -----
1   1              100
2   1              110
3   2              350
4   3              125
```

In the above table, ShippingList can be updated if its in not-complete state, i.e, items can be modified (even added/deleted) till its shipping status is not COMPLETE.

If multiple users have the application opened simultaneously and are modifying the same ShippingList, they can have different state of Shipping Items locally. If first user confirms the ShippingList and moves it to COMPLETE state and then the 2nd user tries to confirm the stock, he'll end up adding more ShippingItems onto a ShippingList which is already closed.

Need here is to somehow check for user 2 before committing that the stock its currently trying to update is already closed/completed.

How can I achieve that? Am using MS SQL server.

**EDIT** : How can I write a trigger on ShippingListItems table to do a check for status of ShippingList on insert/update?

Comment: can you please post the required output ?

Comment: @mohan111: required is that the commit for user 2 should fail, saying that this ShipingList is already complete. Currently, it ends up adding the Shipping Items from user-2's list to the completed list

Comment: Your application should at very least check the Status of the ShippingList prior to an update attempt -- if COMPLETE, abort and notify user.

Comment: @dean: that would be the ideal world for me :) but unfortunately, the system components are bit distributed and its not entirely possible to check that. that is why I need to push this check down to the DB level. Maybe via a Check Constraint or something, but not sure how to achieve it

Comment: OK, if you're using stored procedures, do the check in the sp. If not, write an instead of trigger on ShippingListItems and check the Status there.

Comment: @dean: am not too sure how to create a trigger that'll take the current item being inserted/updated and check for its corresponding status in the ShippingList. Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: I'd suggest for start to check the SQL Server documentation here:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175521%28v=sql.105%29.aspx. Pls come back if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTE: I have limited access to code, so had to push it down to the DB level which is also the right place for multiple instance of the program running and writing concurrently.

Ended up using a trigger on ShippingListItem and checking the Status of the ShippingList on insert/update. That seems to solve the problem.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[ValidateShippingListItems]
   ON [dbo].[ShippingListItems]
   FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    if exists (select 1 from [dbo].[ShippingList] g inner join inserted i on i.ShippingList_Id = g.Id where g.Status = 3) 
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('Shipping List is already in COMPLETE status',16,1)
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this correctly, you'd need to implement a concurrency pattern.  Which one you choose depends upon how the system is utilized.

It sounds like you want to utilize the Optimistic Locking pattern.  I'd recommend setting a modification date column on the table you're updating.  Then, each consumer of the data would fetch that date along with the data, and when an update is made, they'd pass the date back in.  If the date has changed on the row they're attempting to update, you should raise an error and abort instead of making the update.

If you're looking for a simple solution, though, you could just check the status of that row before committing the change.  Same deal, just bail out before making the change if your status is already closed.  This would probably catch 99.9% of your woes.